# MS Word C# AddIn - how to edit xml of an open word document

Tags: c#, xml, ms-word, add-in, docx

Thanks for coming by :)

I need to **modify the XML of an MS Word Document** directly, because the Word Interop's capabilities are insufficient for what I need to do.
The trick is that I have to do it **from a Word Add-In and apply it to the currently open document**, so I can't open/save packages (right?). In short, several dozen articles like the one below are not applicable here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa982683%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Any help would be appreciated :)

Example problem -- Remove custom cell margins from a really, really big table in word (think 200x10) and check "Same as whole table" for each.

A lead on a solution (currenttable is the currently selected word table):

```
using System.Xml.Linq; // plus all the standard Word Add-In references
...
XDocument currentablexdocument = XDocument.Parse(currenttable.Range.WordOpenXML);
currentablexdocument.Descendants().Where(e =>e.Name.LocalName.Equals("tcMar")).Remove();
currenttable.Range.Delete();
currentselection.InsertXML(currentablexdocument.ToString());
```

Explanation:

- currenttable.Range.WordOpenXML provides me with well-formed XML representation of the table, which I then interpret as an XDocument
- tcMar = table cell margins. These XML elements exist only if a cell has custom margins. Deleting all such elements does **exactly** what I need.
- currenttable.Range.Delete() deletes the old table
- currentselection.InsertXML(...) inserts the modified table XML into the document with margins fixed. Pretty much instantaneous. Yay!

Problem:

- Deleting and inserting the table is flaky and yields undesired results. It would be much better if I could MODIFY the xml directly. Is it possible?

Disclaimer:
Any other ideas of fixing this particular issue are welcome, but I have tried a myriad of possible solutions:

- applying table style rejected by client,
- looping "SendKeys" commands to automate use of the Word interface too unreliable,
- changing Table.XXXPadding, Row.XXXPadding, Column.XXXPadding doesn't affect custom Cell margins (among other issues)
- looping through cells to change their Cell.XXXPadding too slow (Freezes word for several minutes on a 200x10 table). Note, it's accessing the padding that's slow; the loop itself takes 3 seconds to traverse the whole table when implemented correctly.
- ofc I tried it all with ScreenRefreshing = false and AllowAutoFit = false;

Somebody please help :)
Cheers!